# Is it possible to create an Interface with a property type which changes based on another property, without explicity knowing it on compile?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I want to be able to infer an objects property type based on another one of it's properties, without having to declare T, like newType. Instead declaring newType and infering T from a property. See below:

```
export interface Action {
  type: K;
  payload: K extends "UPDATE_FIVE_DAY"
    ? {
        fiveDayForecast?: FiveDayForecast;
        fiveDayExpiresAt?: Moment;
        fiveDayLocationFor?: Location;
      }
    : K extends "UPDATE_LOADING"
    ? { loading: boolean }
    : K extends "UPDATE_LOCATION"
    ? { location: Location }
    : K extends "UPDATE_SETTINGS"
    ? { settings: Settings }
    : undefined;
}
```

The issue I have is that the variable `K` does not exist, I can set it up like:

```
export interface Action<K extends 'UPDATE_FIVE_DAY' | 'UPDATE_LOADING' | ...etc
```

However then I need to declare the type of action.type, which I do not necessarily know. I want to use the type as below:

I want to use this Action in a generic reducer as such:

```
export default (state: State = initialState, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
      };
  }
});
```

However the return statement throws a type error as it thinks action.payload could be any of the possible return types. Which is not true.

Comment: You can use [discriminated-unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), see also [official redux dosc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)

Comment: [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) might be useful here.

Comment: @OSH As you can se in my example, conditional types require I define the Type when calling, and also TS still assumes Payload can be any of the types.

Comment: @Shlang Have managed a working prototype with discriminated Unions, a bit more overhead than I wanted but works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using Discriminated Unions, as suggested by @shlang.

Reducer:

```
export default (state: State = initialState, action: Actions): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload.loading,
      };
   }
});
```

and the types for the actions:

```
export type Action = {
  type: AllActionTypes;
  payload: Partial<State> | undefined;
};

export type Actions =
  | UpdateFiveDayAction
  | UpdateLoadingAction;


export interface UpdateLoadingAction extends Action {
  type: "UPDATE_LOADING";
  payload: { loading: State["loading"] };
}


export interface UpdateFiveDayAction extends Action {
  type: "UPDATE_FIVE_DAY";
  payload: {
    fiveDayForecast: State["fiveDayForecast"];
    fiveDayExpiresAt: State["fiveDayExpiresAt"];
    fiveDayLocationFor: State["fiveDayLocationFor"];
  };
}
```