# How would you suggest to merge interfaces with same properties but different value types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm using `useReducer` on ReactJS and I've defined a couple of action interfaces to use them in my `reducer function`. I see that I use the same properties, but sometimes different payload values.

```
interface MembersAction {
  type: "JOIN" | "LEAVE";
  payload: string;
}

interface MessagesAction {
  type: "MESSAGE";
  payload: Message;
}

interface ErrorAction {
  type: "ERROR";
  payload: string;
}

interface RoomAction {
  type: "ROOM";
  payload: RoomData;
}
```

To be honest it feels like bloat and I feel like there must be a better way to achieve what I'm doing.

Here's the reducer function:

```
type Action = MembersAction | MessagesAction | RoomAction | ErrorAction;

const reducer = (state: RoomState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "JOIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        members: [...state.members, action.payload],
      };
    case "LEAVE":
      return {
        ...state,
        members: state.members.splice(state.members.indexOf(action.payload), 1),
      };
    case "MESSAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [...state.messages, action.payload],
      };
    case "ROOM":
      return action.payload;
    case "ERROR":
      return state.error
        ? {
            ...state,
          }
        : {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload,
          };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to do this unfortunately. This person had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090145/is-it-possible-to-create-an-interface-with-a-property-type-which-changes-based-o?rq=1) and the answer resembles your solution. You could shorten your code a little by combining the Members and Error actions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, and seems to behave well in this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-y9ACoijQ0FCUOsSAAfgrStzSvcVUPNLosMYM0sJIHDawPStkOUSUHyfDZmlfSt3xIYcfE5OpgFgp14KYXswK6bQgA).

- You've expressed this correctly as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), such that TypeScript is inferring your `payload` type correctly in the `switch` block.
- Your `payload` type is not compatible between your different Actions, so there isn't much to be gained here by treating `payload` polymorphically.
- Your reducer approximates the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), though Typescript's structural typing means you avoid some of the interfaces commonly associated with that pattern. If your reducer expresses an operation that is *intrinsically something an Action should be able to do to itself*, I can see the value in refactoring so every Action supplies an implementation of a method that works like your `reducer` does, but that accepts some class definition boilerplate instead of your `switch` statement boilerplate.

When thinking through this, decide whether it is more likely that you'll be adding Actions that need to express a new behavior (such that the behavior should be encapsulated in an Action), or adding self-contained functions that operate on most or all new actions (such that the behavior should be encapsulated in a `switch` like you have). If it's unclear, leave it—personally I'd gladly accept code as clearly-defined as you have it.