# Polymorphic interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In using the Cheerio library with Typescript, I discovered that the IDE/Typescript compiler is able to discern which `interface` definition should be used to perform type checking based on a member variable.   In the type definitions you can find this:

```js
declare namespace cheerio {
    type Element = TextElement | TagElement | CommentElement;

    interface TextElement {
        type: 'text';
        (other properties)
        ...

    interface TagElement {
        type: 'tag' | 'script' | 'style';
        (other properties)
        ...

    interface CommentElement {
        type: 'comment';
        (other properties)
        ...
```

All three interfaces have different properties associated with them.  From my code I have the following:

```js
  // process all img tags

  const dom = cheerio.load(doc.text);
  const it = dom('img');
  it.each((i, e) => {
    if (e.type === 'tag') {
      const src = e.attribs.src;
    (etc)
```

If the test for `e.type === 'tag'` is not there, or is changed to `'text'` the IDE/compiler correctly notes that the property `attrib` does not exist on interface `TextElement` and treats the code as erroneous.

My question is this:  what rule is the IDE/compiler following that gives it the knowledge that the `type` property is a discriminator between the different possible object types that can be considered an `Element`?  Is this a convention or a documented rule in the specification?

Since you cannot use the `instanceof` operator on Javascript interfaces like you can for classes, this is a very useful feature if it is reliable.  I wasn't aware of this capability before.  Any pointer to normative text or discussion would be appreciated.

---

Please note this is *not* a question about Cheerio so that's why there is no tag for it on this question.

Comment: Discriminated union it is. The act of determining which one is desired is called "narrowing"

Comment: Doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: And technically that is NOT polymorphic interface. Because the value of the `type` field constitutes part of the type signature, they are distinct types combined into a union of types, not a part of a polymorphic sub-type relationship. Though it can be used to simulate that latter.  See also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-4.html#type-guards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you suggest to merge interfaces with same properties but different value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166729/how-would-you-suggest-to-merge-interfaces-with-same-properties-but-different-val)

Comment: The `each` method takes a callback that is typed to take the union type as its second parameter. The type of this method is roughly as follows: `each(cb: (i: number, e: TextElement | TagElement | CommentElement) => void): void`.